# C# Visual Studio - Able to step through breakpoints but not stopping at errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a peculiar thing happening. I have am in Visual Studio 2019 and am able to step through breakpoints, but when I come to a line that has an error, it just throws an exception as if it is in a try / catch and just tripped the catch part.

What should happen is that visual studio usually shows/jumps to the line that has the error and shows the little dialog when you hover over the red circle with the white "X" in it to show what the error is.

Here are the things I have checked:

1. There are no try/catches in my code. only using statements.
2. I am in debug mode, not in release mode
3. My Define Debug constant is set to true
   [image]
4. I am loading the correct .pdb file
5. "Enable just my code" is checked in the options.
6. my "Debuggin information" setting in Advanced build settings is set to "full"
7. I restarted visual studio
8. I restarted my computer.

Does anyone know how to fix this so that it shows the line and the error at which it breaks at?

update:
This is what it should show when a bug is found:
[image]

Comment: _"when I come to a line that has an error, it just throws an exception as if it is in a try / catch and just tripped the catch part"_ I'm not sure I understand this. Can you tell us exactly what happens? Do you get a message box? Does it ignore the exception silently? Something else? Also, does this happen with all exceptions or with a specific type of exception?

Comment: Try ctrl-alt-e. Check "managed exceptions."

Comment: just updated the question with an image to help with the context. my debugger was not showing the error(the debugger image in the question under "update". )

Comment: You could wrap the DataGridView1.Rows.Add (row) in a Try Catch.
But the error is telling you...you cant add a row to a data-bound control. You need to add the row to the table (I guess) and refresh the control.

Answer (score -1):

Of course, once I post my own question, I somehow figure it out.

This issue still confuses me but what fixed it for me was just adding this line to my form1_load:

`throw new FileNotFoundException(@"show random bug here");`

I suspect I could have added it anywhere, even in my main(), so long as it was tripped and "reset the debugger"

After putting this line in my code and running it, the broke at the line and showed everything correctly. After that, I was able to comment out the line and run my code. now the debugger shows where it's breaking normally and showing the line along with the error. weird.

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Not my downvote, but several possibilites. 1, you didn't show where you added this to your original code. 2, this gives you want you want, but it doesn't answer the question. The original question was "the debugger is highlighting line X on exception, it's not showing line A, the line that actually caused the exception." 3, your original question is still missing context as of this comment. It shows where you want to see the debugger stop, but not where it was stopping originally. The way this question and answer are structured, they are not likely to be helpful to others in the future.

Comment: @PatrickTucci, thank you for letting me know. I edited the answer to let others know where I placed the line. for your #3, the debugger wasnt stopping at a line (as is shown in the image)when it found an error. At the time, it was just crashing/closing the program and stopping the debugger. I believe the line I added in the answer helped "reset" the debugger settings somehow... As you can tell, I had trouble explaining the issue :-\. It was difficult to explain something that after, 5 years of coding, I've never seen the debugger have this issue. Will try to do better on the next one.